# Automatic Package Restore fails on TFS Build but works in VS

Tags: c#, msbuild, tfsbuild, nuget-package-restore

I migrated my solution to NuGet's recommendation of Automatic Package Restore.

Source structure (abbreviated):

```
MyProject
  |- MyProject.sln
  |- .nuget
    |- NuGet.config
    |- NuGet.exe
  |- MyProject
    |- MyProject.csproj
    |- packages.config
  |- packages
    |- repositories.config
  |- .tfignore
```

NuGet.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="LocalRepo" value="http://ourlocalrepo/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

MyProject.csproj changes:

Added target:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="RestorePackages;Build" ...
...
<Target Name="RestorePackages">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(SolutionDir).nuget\NuGet.exe&quot; restore &quot;$(SolutionPath)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Now this works perfectly running MSBuild form:

- Visual Studio
- Commandline
- Commandline from build server logged in as build agent user

But when I queue a build, the build fails with: 
`The command ""C:\Builds\3\Myproject\src\.nuget\NuGet.exe" restore "C:\Builds\3\MyProject\src\MayProject.sln"" exited with code 1.`

Even if I execute that same command manually via commandline (and not msbuild) it succeeds and restores the packages.

Current (dirty) workaround: I restore the packages on the build server and don't do a clean. The other option is to commit the packages to source control which I don't really want to do.

I have proxy settings in my nuget.config.

The setup seems fine and I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Did you see this blog [post](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/debugging-nuget-package-restore)?

Comment: Ok wait, I was being in idiot. The actual user account I thought it was running as was not the one it ran as. See, the build account that accesses the source does not have internet access, while the account with internet access does not have tfs access. Luckily you can configure the build server to use different accounts to access tfs and run the service as.